# Symfony 2 console error

Tags: css, symfony

I'm new in Symfony2. I've changed my css and when I try to install again my modifications in eclipse shell it gives me an error:

> 'C:\wamp\www\Symfony' is not recognized as an internal or external
>   command, operable program or batch file.

I put this line of code `C:\wamp\www\Symfony> php app/console/install`

Anyone can help me please?

Comment: You put that line of code where? In cmd.exe or powershell or in the eclipse console/prompt? Also the easiest way i find to invoke these commands is with an External tool in eclipse pointing to the necessary scripts and the using `${string_prompt}` like: `/path/to/php ${project_loc}/app/console ${string_prompt}`

Comment: Is that `'` (apostrophe) part of the actual error? Could it have been a type?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done Symfony2 development on windows for a while, nor used Eclipse fully, but I believe this might help.

Right click on My Computer and go to properties > Advanced > Environment Variables > System Variables.

In that window select "path" and click the edit button. Go to the end of "Variable Value" and append this value

```
;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.X
```

IMPORTANT: Make sure to replace `php5.3.X` with whatever the name of the php directory is under `C:\wamp\bin\php\`

Then you can run

```
> cd C:\wamp\www\Symfony
> php app/console install
```

Answer (score 0):

The command you are looking for is:

`php app/console assets:install web`

that will install all the files from the 'public' folder in your 'src/Vendor/SomeBundle' into the 'web/bundles' directory.